# document object points to iframe document

Tags: javascript, iframe

I'm trying to understand what's happening in my code.

So what I'm doing is
1. Iframe in a page - points to aspx page with some javascript. Worth noting its same domain so no issues with access.
2. Code in iframe window gets parent document object and injects requirejs into parent head with config in place to load my-custom-code.js
3. so my-custom-code.js is loaded into the head of the parent page and runs fine.

!!! This is what I don't get !!!
When I try to use window and document in my-custom-code.js they actually point to child(iframe) document and window???

So I want to understand HOW IT WORKS.

Thanks

**UPDATE: iframe js file**

```
var $doc = $(parent.document);
var head = $doc.find("head");
var body = $doc.find("body");
var reqConfigScript = "<script class='require-default-config'>var require = { deps: ['http:\/\/localhost/scripts/parent-main.js'], callback: function(main){ } };</script>";
body.append(reqConfigScript);
var parentScript = "<script src='http:\/\/" + location.host + "/scripts/require-2.1.11.min.js' type=\"text/javascript\"></script>";
head.append(parentScript);
```

Comment: Can you please show the code you have to inject your JS file? I have a hunch, but your code will help confirm it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, it's a bit hard to guess because I don't know exactly how the library works... but try this:

```
parent.require = {
    deps: ['http:\/\/localhost/scripts/parent-main.js'],
    callback: function(main){ }
};
var parentScript = parent.document.createElement('script');
// important to use `parent.document` so the right document owns the script
parentScript.src = "http://"+location.host+"/script/require-2.1.11.min.js";
parentScript.type = "text/javascript";
parent.document.body.appendChild(parentScript);
```

Comment: Nice 1, now I get the parent document object within the script.
But question still remains - WHY?:)

Comment: Because the owner document of the script was wrong. This method ensures the owner is correct. I guess the library you're using didn't plan for this use case. This is why [Vanilla JS](http://vanilla-js.com/) is so awesome :p

Comment: lol, for a second I thought it's a real framework :DDD
ok, thanks a lot!